# Disable multiple input field

Tags: apex, visualforce

I want to disable multiple apex:inputText.
1.Click the checkbox.
2.I want to Disable inputText.

I can disable single inputText.
But, I can't assigne the same id to other apex:inputText.
What should I do?

```
<apex:page controller="EntryController" showHeader="true" sidebar="false" title="サンプル" docType="html-5.0" id="page" tabStyle="Account"  >

<apex:sectionHeader id="header" title="サンプル"/>
<apex:form >
    <div id="all">
        <div id="form">
            <apex:outputPanel >
                <apex:pageBlock title="配送先">
                    <apex:pageBlockSection >
                        <apex:inputField value="{!newContract.isShippingSame__c}">
                            <apex:actionSupport reRender="isSame" event="onchange" />
                        </apex:inputField><div/>
                        <apex:inputText value="{!newContract.ShippingAddressee__c}" label="発送先名" id="isSame" disabled="{!newContract.isShippingSame__c}" /><br/>
                        <apex:inputText value="{!shippingPostalcode}" label="郵便番号" />
                        <apex:inputText value="{!shippingState}" label="住所にする"/>
                        <apex:inputText value="{!newContract.RecieverName__c}" label="受取者名" />
                        <apex:inputText value="{!newContract.RecieverPhone__c}" label="受取者TEL" />                        
                    </apex:pageBlockSection>
                </apex:pageBlock>
            </apex:outputPanel>
        </div>
    </div>

</apex:form>
```

EntryController.apxc

```
    public class EntryController {

        public Contract__c newContract{get; set;}
        public String shippingPostalcode{get; set;}
　　　　public String shippingState{get; set;}

        // コンストラクタ
        public EntryController(){
            this.newContract=new Contract__c();
            this.newContract.isShippingSame__c=false;
　　　　　　 this.shippingPostalcode='';
       　　 this.shippingState='';
        }
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can disable the individual `inputText`'s by reRendering all the `inputText`'s again by passing comma separated `Id`'s in the `reRender` attribute of `actionSupport`.

```
<apex:pageBlockSection >
    <apex:inputField value="{!newContract.isShippingSame__c}">
        <apex:actionSupport reRender="isSame1,isSame2,isSame3,isSame4,isSame5" event="onchange" />
    </apex:inputField><div/>
    <apex:inputText value="{!newContract.ShippingAddressee__c}" label="発送先名" id="isSame1" disabled="{!newContract.isShippingSame__c}" /><br/>
    <apex:inputText value="{!shippingPostalcode}" label="郵便番号" id="isSame2" disabled="{!newContract.isShippingSame__c}"/>
    <apex:inputText value="{!shippingState}" label="住所にする" id="isSame3" disabled="{!newContract.isShippingSame__c}"/>
    <apex:inputText value="{!newContract.RecieverName__c}" label="受取者名" id="isSame4" disabled="{!newContract.isShippingSame__c}"/>
    <apex:inputText value="{!newContract.RecieverPhone__c}" label="受取者TEL" id="isSame5" disabled="{!newContract.isShippingSame__c}"/>                        
</apex:pageBlockSection>
```

Comment: by passing comma! I see.  Thank you so much !